# jQuery AJAX request changes the webpage location in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I've recently programmed a new website. The website works just as expected in all major browsers. My website is for IE8+. I wanted to try my website on IE8 and found that obviously some of my plugins doesn't work such as [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/index.html) but that doesn't really bother me at all. There is one thing which bothers me.

For some reason, IE8 Won't recognize my AJAX request and whenever the form is being submitted, it is not being stop by jQuery and being submitted "behind the scenes" but it actually goes to the form action.

here is my code:

```
$('form.contact-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    /* Change button text */
    var button = form.find('button[type=submit]');
    var originalButtonText = button.text();
    button.text('שולח...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    var url = form.prop('action');
    var data = {
        '_token': form.find('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'name' : form.find('input[name=name]').val(),
        'email' : form.find('input[name=email]').val(),
        'phone' : form.find('input[name=phone]').val(),
        'subject' : form.find('input[name=subject]').val(),
        'message' : form.find('textarea').val()
    };


    $.post(url, data, function(r) {

        processFormSubmitResult(r);
        button.text(originalButtonText).removeAttr('disabled');

    }, 'json');


});
```

Why is that happening?

### EDIT:

I've altered my code a bit so I can see if the submit function even triggers by changing the button text. It doesn't work. The code it never being executed

Comment: That code looks okay. Can you replicate it with a [minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: When you say other things are not working, do you mean you get a javascript error in the console? It might result in this piece of code not executing at all.

Comment: @red-X The only error that is being generated is related to WOW.js. I've also investigated that part already. However, there is a JS file after wow.js which executes and operates just as it should, so I'm not sure it is actually stopping the scripts from being executed :/

Comment: there might some other javascript error preventing jQuery from executing. or maybe you should add a return false; to the bottom of the script ...

Comment: @jao: kfirba's doing `e.preventDefault()`, which is entirely sufficient to stop the form submission.

Comment: @jao I've checked that already. The JS files are as follows: 1. jQuery.js 2.plugins.js (which wow.js located in) 3. main.js The code within main.js does execute since there is some code before the form submit event which also uses jQuery that actually works

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but you know, IE8 and stuff...

Comment: @jao I've also tried that before posting my question here. Tried returning false at the end of the script rather than using `e.preventDefault()` still, no effect whatsoever.